# Is there a point to having a large IV in AES

Tags: aes

I've always known that the IV should be 128 bits, because that's the block size of AES, regardless of the key.

However, I just saw one vendor advertising AES-256 with a 256 bit IV.

Is there any point to that? Does a 'double' IV bring additional guarantees? For example, reducing the probability of having the same IV with the same key?

Will it even work with standard AES implementations, or they'll reject it? The Java implementation rejects it, for example.

Effectively, it adds another block of plaintext to throw away, but if it works, does it have negative effects (apart from having one more block to process)

Or is it just a marketing mistake...

Comment: @Bozho Why not point them out? If it is marketing material then it is supposed to be public, right? Then we can look at their claims.

Comment: There you go https://www.bitglass.com/cloud-encryption :)

Comment: I didn't mention the mode because I don't know which one it is. I'd assume GCM or CBC, but who knows..

Comment: Well, one can ask them as I did now.

Comment: My snake oil detector goes all crazy multiple times on these two sentences: "(smurf) Cloud Encryption is patented, FIPS compliant 256-bit AES encryption with 256-bit initialization vectors. Only (smurf) provides industry standard, military grade encryption without compromising application functionality" ! I do not make that up !

Comment: As a rule of thumb: Tinkering with AES in general is a sign that a person or company has no knowledge about cryptography. That usually goes against "don't invent your own crypto". Exceptions might exist - but those would be based on publications in the field and scientific evidence, that some change is a non-marginal improvement over the current state of the art.

Comment: Wow. Might not be snake oil, but they are completely dishonest for starters. Only they provide "military grade" encryption? That's just a load of ... well, you know what.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I've always known that the IV should be 128 bits, because that's the block size of AES, regardless of the key.

The IV depends on the mode of operation. It may well be that the block mode of operation specifies to use the block size, but this is not a given. For instance, AES-GCM defaults to 96 bits.

For CTR mode it is rather common to supply an IV, but in reality that consists of a nonce and a starting counter value; you could have implementations / protocols that only expect the nonce as input, which would then be smaller than 128 bits.

> However, I just saw one vendor advertising AES-256 with a 256 bit IV.

Not many modes support that, so I'm wondering how they accomplished that. AES-GCM does support it, but at the expense of additional calculations. Furthermore, it doesn't increase security at all. It doesn't make much sense for AES-CBC mode either, as the second ciphertext block will be the IV, i.e. the effective IV would still be 128 bits.

The other more likely option is that they use Rijndael with a block size of 256 bits. In that case it is not AES (which is Rijndael with a block size of 128 bits and only 3 key sizes with the default number of rounds configured). In that case they really don't know what they are doing.

> Is there any point to that? Does a 'double' IV bring additional guarantees? For example, reducing the probability of having the same IV with the same key?

No generally it doesn't bring any benefits. As it is hard to use AES in such a way that the block size of 128 bits isn't a limiting factor (e.g. when it comes to processing a huge amount of blocks), I don't see how a larger IV would alleviate that issue.

> Will it even work with standard AES implementations, or they'll reject it? The Java implementation rejects it, for example.

Again, it depends on the mode; GCM may grog it. Java simply keeps to the standards, I've not seen Oracle deviate all that much yet.

> Effectively, it adds another block of plaintext to throw away, but if it works, does it have negative effects (apart from having one more block to process)

Again, depends on the mode and how it is configured.

> Or is it just a marketing mistake...

I might well be a marketing mistake. That's pretty likely actually. An engineering mistake (AES vs Rijndael) is also likely. It could however also be snake oil although you should not attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity.

However, definitive statements can only be made after more detailed analysis, and for that we need the source. I'd have *them* explain it to you.

Comment: "Very likely it is stupidity or snake oil, especially if it is explicitly marketed as such" - it could also be an inadvertent error, added by a marketing person who didn't understand the technology; if that were the case, the product might be quite sound (not claiming that it is, merely that it is a viable possibility)

Comment: yeah, true, I should take the razor into account